# ASP.Net Gridview.Rows.Count is giving wrong count

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

I have a Gridview (BudgetGridView) that is paginated by default, at 30 rows per page. Once per year, the data in this gridview gets updated.  To allow this, I am enabling editing on all rows of this gridview using some really slick code I found online (http://highoncoding.com/). As part of that editing process, I disable the pagination so the user can easily edit and scroll the entire gridview till they hit the bottom and save all their edits in one action.  That pagination disable happens here:

```
        if (myLabel == "  Edit All  ")
        {
            isEditMode = true;
            BudgetGridView.AllowPaging = false;
            EditAllButton.Text = "  Save Edits  ";
            BindBudgetGridView();
        }
```

The gridview is fully editable at this point, and it works beautifully.  When the user Saves, hitting the "else" of the code above, I run into the problem that is the subject of this posting. Here is that else:

```
        else
        {
            isEditMode = false;
            EditAllButton.Text = "  Edit All  ";
            SaveData();  // Problem is here...
            BudgetGridView.AllowPaging = true;
            BindBudgetGridView();
        }
```

When the call above is made to SaveData() it looks like this:

```
protected void SaveData()
    {
        // total count for an update loop
        int totalRowsCount = BudgetGridView.Rows.Count;
```

Rather than return the correct count (roughly 250 rows) it is giving me a value of 30, which is the pagination value, but pagination is disabled.  If it helps, here are the properties of the gridview:

```
                <asp:GridView 
                    ID="BudgetGridView" runat="server"
                    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#FFFFFF" 
                    ShowFooter="True" 
                    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#546E96"
                    FooterStyle-BackColor="#C3CFDD" 
                    AllowPaging="True" 
                    PageSize="30" 
                    OnPageIndexChanging="BudgetGridView_PageIndexChanging"
                    AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#FFFFCC"  
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataKeyNames="KeyID"   
                    BackColor="White"
                    HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                    OnRowDeleting="BudgetGridView_RowDeleting"
                    EnableViewState="false">
```

Any thoughts on why I am getting a row count of 30 rather than the full 250 or so?

Comment: You probably want to use the 'rowcount' from your datasource rather than the GridView.

Comment: This smells like a page lifecycle issue. At what point in the page lifecycle does the if/else statement you mentioned happen?

Comment: Colin, if I understand your question correctly, the page is fully loaded, the user has examined the data and made a decision to click the "Edit All" button.  This changes the GridView ItemTemplate items to textfields.  The user has made the edits and clicked the same button which now reads "Save Edits"  and that brings us to the count problem. At this point we are in the "Else" of the If/Else above, and have moved into the SaveData section.

Comment: Dave, I had the same thought.  I may have to go that route.  I am just hard-headed enough, however, to want to make this GridView row count work.  That's why we have it.  ;-)  I really need to work on this hard-headedness.

Comment: Gah!!  Dave and Colin, I did use the count from the DB (1041, way more than 200) to get around this, and interestingly in my update loop, once it hits 30 (31st record starting with 0) I get an index out of range exception, which indicates to me that it is trying to get data from row 31 of the Gridview but believes there are only 30 on the page.  I am LOOKING at the full gridview with 1041 records. 

Colin, can you elaborate on the page lifecycle concept?  The code-behind is convinced that there are only 30 rows in the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!

The solution is to handle pagination in the codebehind and remove it from the aspx.  So long as it is in the properties of the GridView in the aspx, nothing I do in the codebehind has any effect.  So, I changed the aspx to this:

```
                <asp:GridView 
                ID="BudgetGridView" runat="server"
                HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#FFFFFF" 
                ShowFooter="True" 
                HeaderStyle-BackColor="#546E96"
                FooterStyle-BackColor="#C3CFDD" 
                OnPageIndexChanging="BudgetGridView_PageIndexChanging"
                AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#FFFFCC"  
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="KeyID"   
                BackColor="White"
                HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                OnRowDeleting="BudgetGridView_RowDeleting"
                EnableViewState="false">
```

... and placed these statements where I needed them in the codebehind:

```
            //kill pagination
        BudgetGridView.AllowPaging = false;
        BudgetGridView.PageSize = 5000;

        //resurrect pagination
        BudgetGridView.AllowPaging = true;
        BudgetGridView.PageSize = 30;
```

Now, we're cooking with gas!!

Thanks for your help.